# Unable to load an excel file in R. Extension .xls but signature .xlsx

Tags: r

I have multiple .xls files from which I would like to read them all.
I used whatever attempt I search in internet but still not able to solve it. But these are the information I have found... as below :

```
    > df <- read_excel("report.xls")
    Error: 
    filepath: C:\Users\abc\Desktop\file1\report.xls

    > libxls error: Unable to open file
        file.exists("report.xls")
    [1] TRUE

    > format_from_ext("report.xls")
    [1] "xls"

    > format_from_signature("report.xls")
    [1] "xlsx"
```

Need your help to help me to solve this problem...

Comment: Well since you know that the format is XLSX, try using `read_xlsx()` instead of `read_excel()`. [As per the documentation](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html), this is required for files with an incorrect extension.

Comment: @jay.sf , it is the prompt showed by R in terminal after I excecute the function `format_from_signature ()`

Comment: Hi @KonradRudolph , indeed I have tried by using `read_xlsx()` and `read_excel()` but the same error was shown...

Comment: @Gambit Is the error message really *exactly* the same?! That’s impossible, since `read_xlsx()` does not use libxls.

Comment: Hey @KonradRudolph! omg! It works after I restart the session and tried again... from this incident, is it we have choose the function that refer to the `format_from_signature()` ? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the signature the file is using the wrong extension, so [`read_excel()` infers the wrong file type](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html).

Since you know the correct file type (via `format_from_signature()`), you can override the incorrectly inferred file type by directly calling `read_xlsx()`.